# Receiver type 'WebFrame' for instance message is a forward declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, forward-declaration

I'm learning ObjC and cocoa dev and have come across a real 'stumper'. Having exhausted Google, I respectfully adorn my desperation hat and present to you:

A class and a view controller:

The class 'Content Window' imports a viewcontroller instance and places it in a window:

ContentWindow.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WebKit/WebView.h>
#import "ContentViewController.h"
@interface ContentWindow : NSWindow{
    ContentViewController* viewController;
}
@property IBOutlet ContentViewController* viewController;
-(NSWindow *) newWindow;
@end
```

ContentWindow.m

```
#import "ContentWindow.h"
@implementation ContentWindow

@synthesize viewController;
-(NSWindow *) newWindow{
    //Builds the window  as 'window' and displays it successfully here
    //... [code redacted for brevity]

    // Build view
    viewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];
    [window setContentView: viewController.view];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
    [[viewController.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
    [viewController.title setStringValue:@"my title"];
}
@end
```

I am attempting to do two things with the interface:

```
[viewController.title setStringValue:@"my title"];
```

This successfully sets the view element 'title' to "my title".

```
[[viewController.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

This, however, throws the error:

```
Receiver type 'WebFrame' for instance message is a forward declaration.
```

and underlines in red the section of the line:

```
viewController.webView mainFrame
```

My view controller is as follows:

ContentViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebView.h>
@interface ContentViewController : NSViewController {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *title;
    IBOutlet WebView *webView;
}
@property IBOutlet WebView *webView;
@property IBOutlet NSTextField *title;
@end
```

ContentViewController.m

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"
@interface ContentViewController ()
@end
@implementation ContentViewController
@synthesize  title, webView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) { 
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

Finally to use this class, I am instantiating a content window from my AppDelegate class with

```
contentWindow = [[ContentWindow new] newWindow];
```

Having imported ContentWindow.h into AppDelegate.h and having set:

```
__strong NSWindow * contentWindow
```

as an AppDelegate synthesised instance variable.

I have linked both items in IB (definitely!) I have also added Webkit foundation to my project, which was suggested in another thread.

I can't for the life of me understand what is going on. I know that the logical answer is to put down Xcode and pick up the 'Learn Xcode and Objective c' book (with a bookmark about half way through where I was arrogant enough to think I'd learned enough to try something out), but before I do that, on the off-chance:

Could anyone help?

Thanks as always, AtFPt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error message means, that the type of a class is not know (since declared by @class).
Make sure, that your code can see a declaration of `WebFrame`.
If so, maybe you add it later and XCode works with older meta data. In this case, a clean before build usually helps.

Comment: I marked this as correct with this addendum: Searched for 'WebFrame' class, found it was part of <WebKit/WebKit.h>, saw that i was importing <WebKit/WebView.h>. Added WebKit to the imports. Worked first time. Thanks.